# foreach with two kind of values

Tags: php, api, loops, foreach

```
<?php
foreach ($array['response']['data']['Offers'] as $arr) {
    $gegevens = array(
        $arr['Offer']['id'],
        $arr['Offer']['name'],
        $arr['Advertiser']['company'],
        $arr['Offer']['advertiser_id'],
        $arr['Offer']['offer_url'],
        $arr['Offer']['default_payout'],
        $arr['Offer']['expiration_date']
    );
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($gegevens as $value) {
        echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
```

This is the code I have.
How can I search for two kind of values inside the `foreach($array['response']['data']`?

It has to be `foreach($array['response']['data'][**Offers**]` and also `foreach($array['response']['data'][**Advertisers**]`.

I need this so that I can echo out `$arr['**Offer**']['name']`, `$arr['**Advertiser**'] ['company']`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How do you search for the single one? This normally works the same, you just do it with both and combine the results with a logical operator like *and* or *or* regarding what your needs are, e.g. should both be matched (and) or is it enough if one of the two matches (or). http://php.net/expressions http://php.net/operator http://php.net/control-structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its simplest:

```
foreach($array['response']['data']['Offers'] as $key => $offer_arr){
    $advertiser_arr = $array['response']['data']['Advertisers'][$key];
}
```

You then have offer array and advertiser array of the same index

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like you need to put them all into an array. This should suffice:

```
<?php
    foreach($array['response']['data']['Offers'] as $arr) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>{$arr['Offer']['name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$arr['Advertiser']['company']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
?>
```